# Unclear Error Message while Typesetting on MacTeX

Tags: beamer, errors, mactex

I have made my class notes in LaTeX. Up until now, I had not gotten any prominent errors while typesetting. Now, I seem to be getting an error on a part of the document I made no change on. I do not understand why this error is popping up. It seemed to near about this time that I installed Homebrew and changed its path location as is required on Apple Silicon machines, could that be the source of the problem, because on the Overleaf editor, my LaTeX code runs just fine.

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: The .aux file seems to be incomplete.  Delete it and compile again

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I did do that. But now I'm presented with this error: Overfull \hbox (8.97209pt too wide) detected at line 425
[][]
[27] [28]
./Class Notes.tex:452: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<recently read> &
                 
l.452 \end{frame}
                 
?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Besides, the issue with the .aux file is coming up repetitively, do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks. The issue was sorted. :)

Comment: The issue about `Misplaced alignment tab character &` is something else.  I'd need to see the code to tell.  The `.aux` being incomplete is usually due to interrupting the compilation midway, or maybe other errors.  Without seeing the code it's hard to give a definitive answer

Comment: when you get an error allow tex to close gracefully don't just kill the process (eg by deleting the window) as that leaves the aux file partially written and it can then generate an error on the next run.